# Avoid call by reference

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a list of search results with some objects:

```
SearchResults = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel<Consignor>>();
```

I'm trying to save the first object in this list to a new variable:

```
Consignor foundConsignor = consignors.First();
```

As far as I know this is a call by reference. By changing the object "foundConsignor", the first object in my list is changed as well. How can I avoid this behaviour? I could call the constructor of Consignor and pass it the object or the values but I'd like to avoid this as well to keep complexity on a low level.

Comment: Search for making a `deep copy` of an object - e.g. via a serialize / deserialize cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement [IClonable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) on your `Consignor` class and then you can easily do something like `consignors.First().Clone()`.

If your class (`Consignor`) contains intrinsic types only (`int`, `char`, `string` etc.), [MemberwiseClone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx) might be enough for you. But if it contains non-intrinsic type or reference types and you want to perform a deep copy of the members, you'll need to implement `IClonable`.